# How To Recover Oracle 10g Database From A Hard Disk Crash

Tags: windows, oracle10g

I have a legacy application running Oracle 10g on a Windows environment. We had a hard disk crash recently. Thankfully we were able to copy out all files in oradata directory. However, I have not been able recover the data from these files. I really need to recover the data. Please, any assistance will be appreciated.

Among other things, I had created a new database using the same name and restored the data files to the same directory, this has not worked.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. You may be better asking on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ (however, the best solution would be to restore from backups - You did backup your database didn't you? And store the backups safely off-site?)

Comment: Many thanks for your response. There wasn't any recent backup.